# How to write quotes in set elements

Tags: xml, ms-access, dom, vba, ms-access-2010

How to write quotes in this example?

```
Set elem1 = doc.createElement("ReferencniDokumenti VrstaDokumenta="ON"")
```

Comment: Have you tried using `&quot;` in place of `"` within the (quoted) string literal? For example `" ... = &quot;ON&quot;"`

Answer (score 0):

This works :

```
"""" & strFoo & """"
```

However when you have a lot of that it tends to turn your code difficult to read.

So what I usually do is creating a constant handling quote / doublequote, and use a temp variable

```
Public Const DBLEQUOTE As String = """"
' Alternative : Public Const DBLEQUOTE As String = Chr(34)

dim strTemp as string
strTemp = "ReferencniDokumenti VrstaDokumenta=" & DBLEQUOTE  & "ON" & DBLEQUOTE 
Set elem1 = doc.createElement(strTemp)
```

Clear, understandable and easy to manipulate.
Not tested in VBA editor, I hope I did not messed up with those damn doublequotes :-) Anyway you'll get the idea.